# C++ String Instantiation vs strncpy/memcopy

Tags: c++, string, performance, char

I have a situation where I need to parse a lot of little `std::string`s out of a potentially large `std::string`(I'm stress-testing with a 20M `std::string`). I keep track of the index of the beginning of the `std::string` I want to parse out, and when I get to the end of the `std::string` I do a `substr` of the large `std::string`. I then use these `std::string`s that I have parsed out as keys for a `std::map`.

I'm looking to make this run faster by switching to `char*`. What I gather I would need to do is maintain the pointer to the beginning of the string I want to parse out, count the length of the string as I parse it, and then instantiate a new `char*` that holds the length of the parsed out string. I then `strncpy/memcpy` the string into the new `char*`. When I use this new `char*` as a key to a `std::map` I have to provide a comparison functor that will run a `strcmp`.

The way I have things now, it takes 290 ms total on average to parse through the string without inserting into the `std::map` (takes ~450 ms total with inserting). Will switching to `char*` give me significantly (anything 50 ms+) better results?

Comment: No human can answer this question definitively. Run the code and benchmark it.

Comment: No, you shouldn't switch to bare `char*`. Write a new, optimized class instead.

Comment: The best way to find out is to implement the two versions and profile them.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, nobody knows the real answer without trying so you might as well try it yourself. But secondly, we can make an educated guess: probably not; that's all `std::string` is doing internally anyway.

What you should do is make a class that represents a range within an existing string (that is, store a pair of iterators), and use this class as an index to your map. This way you can avoid allocating a bunch of tiny strings, which is almost certainly where most of your performance hit will come from, at least during loading. Then you just keep your source string in memory so the iterators are still valid.

You may also consider `unordered_map` if you mostly perform lookups (you can cache the result of the hash, since you're now working with immutable strings), but again the only way to know if this will be faster is the same method for all performance problems: *testing and data*.

Comment: You don't have to make the class GManNickG described, it already exists in Boost Range. `boost::iterator_range<const char*>`

Comment: ... if you use a `boost::iterator_range<const char*>` as keys in a map, you'll probably need to define a lexical `bool operator<(boost::iterator_range<const char*> const&, boost::iterator_range<const char*> const&)`.